# Compile Newly Created Class And Consume

Tags: c#, reflection, compilation, .net-4.5, .net-assembly

I have a few class which derive from an abstract class and have a property and method.
I get all those classes and use them like this:

```
Assembly mscorlib = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
foreach (Type type in mscorlib.GetTypes())
{
    if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(GrabbersBase)) && !type.IsAbstract)
    {
       GrabbersBase obj = (GrabbersBase)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
       retValue.AddRange(obj.GetImages(tag));
    }
}
```

What I want is:

If I create a class that derives from that abstract class `GrabbersBase` and implements its abstract method, I wanna be able just to paste `MyNewClass.cs` file into the appropriate folder and then app. should have the ability to consume it, with no more interference.

Comment: Where does the code for the abstracted members come from?

Comment: May be someone, who the protocol will be given, will provide me, or by myself

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically compile code can be done.

*How to programmatically compile code using C# compiler.*
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `System.Reflection.Emit` namespace.

[Using Reflection Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx)

Hope this helps.